# Any scalatest matchers for matching json

Tags: json, scala, scalatest, matcher

My test currently expects to match the converted json string from a method under test. I have constructed an expected string to perform the match.

```
val input = Foobar("bar", "foo")
val body = Foobar("bar !!", "foo!!")
val responseHeaders = Map[String, String]("Content-Type" -> "application/json")
val statusCode = "200"
val responseEvent = ResponseEvent(input, body, responseHeaders, statusCode)

val expected ="{\"input\":{\"foo\":\"bar\",\"bar\":\"foo\"},\"body\":{\"foo\":\"bar !!\",\"bar\":\"foo!!\"},\"headers\":{\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\"},\"statusCode\":\"200\"}"

val result = Main.stringifyResponse(responseEvent)

result should be(expected)
```

The string matching is extremely sensitive and fails on any whitespace, also any string written on multiline is not accepted for the test because the result is only available on one line as a result of stringifying using json4s library.

Is there a better way to perform matching on json output without having to do a full blown string comparision using scalatest.

Is there a better approach to create this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options!

1. Use a library like Play Json with which you could box your raw Json String into a JsObject and do the check using Scalatest. If you already use a JSON library, see if you can leverage that!
2. Box your JSON into a case class and check for equality!

Answer (score 3):

checkout https://github.com/stephennancekivell/scalatest-json

```
libraryDependencies += "com.stephenn" %% "scalatest-json-jsonassert" % "0.0.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.stephenn" %% "scalatest-json4s" % "0.0.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.stephenn" %% "scalatest-play-json" % "0.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.stephenn" %% "scalatest-circe" % "0.0.1"
```

It lets you write tests without caring about the whitespace, since its json.

```
    it("should pass matching json with different spacing and order") {
      val input = """
        |{
        | "some": "valid json",
        | "with": ["json", "content"]
        |}
      """.stripMargin

      val expected = """
                    |{
                    | "with": ["json", "content"],
                    |     "some":   "valid json"
                    |}
                  """.stripMargin

      input should matchJson(expected)
    }
```

Comment: Tried to use `scalatest-json-jsonassert`. It looks good form the first sight. Unfortunately, it's useless for me, because author hardcoded `JSONCompareMode.STRICT` which prevents ignore-ordering array comparison. There is [an issue about it](https://github.com/stephennancekivell/scalatest-json/issues/185), opened more than year ago.